# How to prevent rapid page request in php?

Tags: php, mysql

These days i'm searching internet  to secure my codes  and my websites , and one point that I crossed and couldn't find a good and easy to learn solution was how to prevent  rapid page request or in easy term DDOS ( not exactly that )  .

Its really likely to happen if some bot or hackers trying to DDOS  a page , I want a way to stop it ,and user can only click and open a page every 2 seconds  not  requesting lots of queries in less than a second.

my websites' platform is php/mysql

is there anyway to do so ?

thanx

Comment: No chance of stopping a DDOS at PHP level, this question is more suited to serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Apache, you should do this at the server level instead of the application (PHP) level.

Try asking for the proper module on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com).